# Store properties showing on mapStateToProps method but store on redux-dev-tools is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

When I console on line 21 of Bugs.js, its sowing ,me the result of action that i dispathed, but when I am printing the data on in li tag..it's blank. Also the store is not chnaged in redux-dev-tools

That's my App.js code

```
function App() {
  const store = configureStore()
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Bugs />
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

That's Bugs.js

```
const Bugs = (props) => {
    useEffect(props.addBug, [])
    return (
        <ul>
            {
                props.bugs.map(bug => {
                    <li>
                        {bug.description}
                    </li>
                })
            }
        </ul>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log('Aftab', state.bugs);
    return (
        {
            bugs: state.bugs
        })
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return (
        {
            addBug: () => dispatch(addBug({ description: 'Bug 1' }))
        }
    )
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Bugs)
```

And thats reducer

```
let lastId = 0
const slice = createSlice({
    name: 'bugs',
    initialState: [],
    reducers: {
        addBug: (bugs, action) => {
            bugs.push({
                id: lastId++,
                description: action.payload.description,
                resolved: false
            })
        },
        resolveBug: (bugs, action) => {
            const index = bugs.findIndex(b => b.id === action.payload.id)
            bugs[index].resolved = true
        },
        assignBug: (bugs, action) => {
            const index = bugs.findIndex(b => b.id === action.payload.bugId)
            bugs[index].userId = action.payload.userId
        }
    }
})
export const { addBug, resolveBug, assignBug } = slice.actions
export default slice.reducer

export const getBugList = userId => createSelector(
    state => state.entities.bugs,
    bugs => bugs.filter(b => b.userId === userId)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

### **You will need to invoke the function for dispatch to work**

**In your `Bugs.js` change**

```
useEffect(props.addBug, [])
```

**To:**

```
useEffect(props.addBug(), [])
```